# pycurl\requests http post hangs

Tags: python, http-post, tornado, pycurl

I have a tornado API serving post requests in a multi-threading environment. I have just noticed if I send a request from an other python application (using requests or pycurl) it hangs infinitely (no error) if the request takes longer than 5 mins. (It works OK from command line curl or postman (chrome extension)).

Also, I can see in the logs that tornado returns the request OK, it's not picked up on the other end.

I am not sure if this is an issue with tornado or requests/pycurl.

EDIT: I have compared the request line by line from pycurl\requests and curl, they are identical.

thanks,

Comment: can u provide some more info so that i can help. Can u update the question with your code or the request or some logs??